# SharePoint Modern Page does not load properly

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

After creating a modern site page in the modern team site, adding the OOTB web parts in the page, publishing that page then page goes blank. After refreshing some time it does show and sometimes it don't. This same problem occurs while adding the custom web part in the site page. Do any one has gone through this type of problem then please let me know the resolution of this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be worthwhile to try looking at maintenance mode to check for any further information. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/client-side-web-parts-maintenance-mode

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should not face such an issue with SPO Modern Pages any more. This used to happen a few years ago.

- Check if there is a service interruption in your O365 Admin center that relates to SPO
- To test you can also collect a fiddler trace while reproducing the issue.
  The trace should show you what's wrong.

Have a look at this link: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6091

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will test this and let you know.